# Maxwell Laws Summary Diagram - Suggestions that I am missing?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, vector-fields

I have been going through a summary book of Maxwell's equations and hope I have organised this correctly but I think perhaps I am missing things important prompts that I could add? *Image below*

Thanks for your help in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly add the column for [Magnetostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetostatics) or [Magnetoquasistatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetoquasistatic_field) if they are of any interest to you.

Also, you might add [charge conservation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation):
$$
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{J}=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}
$$
this one should fit your way of organizing a summary and slicing the knowledge about Maxwell's equations.